# Sharing implementation between C++ classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I want to be able to share implementation between some, but not all, classes of a same base class. I would like to do this using the multiple inheritance functionality of C++ for sake of conceptual correctness (I know a solution could be to use composition instead).

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "Constructed A" << endl;
    }
    void DoAStuff()
    {
        cout << "Did A stuff" << endl;
    }
};

class I : public virtual A
{
public:
    I()
    {
        cout << "Constructed I" << endl;
    }
    void DoIStuff()
    {
        DoAStuff();
        cout << "Did I stuff" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "Constructed B" << endl;
    }
    void DoBStuff()
    {
        cout << "Did B stuff" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public A, public I
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout << "Constructed C" << endl;
    }
    void DoCStuff()
    {
        cout << "Did C stuff" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public A, public I
{
public:
    D()
    {
        cout << "Constructed D" << endl;
    }
    void DoDStuff()
    {
        cout << "Did D stuff" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Creating a B" << endl;
    B *b = new B();

    cout << "Creating a C" << endl;
    C *c = new C();
    c->DoIStuff();

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

In this example I have the blase class `A`, and 3 classes I want to use derived from `A`: `B`, `C` and `D`.

Both `C` and `D` share common implementation, which I have implemented in a separate class `I` as `DoIStuff()`. Since this implementation needs to do stuff defined in the base class `A`, `I` also inherits `A`. The virtual keyword is there since I only want one instance of `A` when creating a `C` or `D`.

This all seems beautiful and expressive to me, however when I try to compile this (using VC++ compiler of VS 2008) I get the following 2 errors:

```
error C2584: 'C' : direct base 'A' is inaccessible; already a base of 'I'
error C2584: 'D' : direct base 'A' is inaccessible; already a base of 'I'
```

To get this working with multiple inheritance, adding a "placeholder" class (e.g `J`) that inherits `A` (but doesn't do anything else) and inheriting `D` and `C` from this class instead of directly from `A` seems to work. However, This placeholder class makes the code a bit less expressive and makes things hard to understand.

Alternatively, I could have `DoIStuff` take a `A` parameter, which means that `I` wouldn't have to inherit from `A`. However, this would mean I'd have to overload `DoIStuff` in both `D` and `C`.

Does anyone know what the best solution for sharing implementation in this scenario is?

Comment: I was expecting this kind of "answers".

Even though I agree composition should be preferred over inheritance, the hierarchy is the way it is, and for this "insane" hierarchy, inheritance happens to be more suitable than composition in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
1. class D : public virtual A, public I

2. class C : public virtual A, public I
```

Otherwise the diamond for the multiple inheritance cannot be set up correctly.

Do also read up on the curiously recurring template pattern. This could be a feasible alternative.

Comment: Ow, that is a pretty simple solution. The CRTP looks interesting, but I think it will make my code more complex than it needs to be.